# Stretchy UIBezierPath line?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibezierpath, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I want to draw a straight line with my finger that automatically sizes based upon how far away I am from the point of origin.

So if I touch the screen in the middle and slide my finger out a line appears to 'stretch' and  pivot around the point of orgin as my finger moves on the screen. WHhen I lift my finger. The Destination Point should finalize and create a line. I can drag my finger across the screen and 'Draw' on the screen but that's not what I am wanting to do.

I thought UIBeizerPath moveToPoint would help but it just messes things up.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
     //default line properties
    myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    myPath.lineCapStyle=kCGLineCapRound;
    myPath.miterLimit=0;
    myPath.lineWidth=lineWidth;
    brushPattern=[UIColor blackColor];
 }



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    lastPoint = curPoint;

    [myPath moveToPoint:lastPoint];
    [pathArray addObject:myPath];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    myPath.lineWidth=lineWidth;
    brushPattern=[UIColor redColor]; //red to show it hasn't been added yet.
    [myPath moveToPoint:tempPoint];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    myPath.lineWidth=lineWidth;

    brushPattern=[UIColor blackColor]; //finalize the line with black color
    [myPath addLineToPoint:curPoint];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one concept. Draws a line from where you start dragging your finger until where you let go, animating it as you drag your finger around. It does this by making a `CAShapeLayer`, resetting the `path` as you move your finger around.

This should demonstrate the basic idea:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)createShapeLayer:(UIView *)view {
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

    shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;

    [view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

    return shapeLayer;
}

- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    static CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;
    static CGPoint origin;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        shapeLayer = [self createShapeLayer:gesture.view];
        origin = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    } else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path moveToPoint:origin];
        CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
        [path addLineToPoint:location];
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    } else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
               gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ||
               gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
        shapeLayer = nil;
    }
}
```

Or, in Swift 3:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
}

private func createShapeLayer(for view: UIView) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    return shapeLayer
}

private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
private var origin: CGPoint!

func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
        shapeLayer = createShapeLayer(for: gesture.view!)
        origin = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
    } else if gesture.state == .changed {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: origin)
        path.addLine(to: gesture.location(in: gesture.view))
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    } else if gesture.state == .ended || gesture.state == .failed || gesture.state == .cancelled {
        shapeLayer = nil
    }
}
```

---

If you don't use `CAShapeLayer`, but you want to keep track of previous paths, you'll have to maintain an array for those old paths, and build a path that consists of all of the old paths, perhaps something like:

```
@interface CustomView ()

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint originPoint;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint currentPoint;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *previousPaths;

@end

@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)configure {
    _previousPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    UIBezierPath *drawPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    drawPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    drawPath.miterLimit = 0;
    drawPath.lineWidth = 3.0;

    for (UIBezierPath *path in self.previousPaths)
        [drawPath appendPath:path];

    UIBezierPath *path = [self pathForCurrentLine];
    if (path)
        [drawPath appendPath:path];

    [drawPath stroke];
}

- (UIBezierPath *)pathForCurrentLine {
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(self.originPoint, CGPointZero) && CGPointEqualToPoint(self.currentPoint, CGPointZero))
        return nil;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:self.originPoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:self.currentPoint];

    return path;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.originPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([event respondsToSelector:@selector(predictedTouchesForTouch:)]) {
        touch = [[event predictedTouchesForTouch:touch] lastObject] ?: touch;
    }
    self.currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.currentPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [self.previousPaths addObject:[self pathForCurrentLine]];
    self.originPoint = self.currentPoint = CGPointZero;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks that was deal. Saving them into an array and redrawing. Any chance that is going to come back and bite me in the future?

Comment: I can't imagine any issues. There ain't much there! But you get the basic issues at play, so if you need to pursue other implementations at some future date, you're well armed.

Comment: I appreciate all your help! It drove me mad!

Comment: Any thoughts on how to make each line colored differently? @Rob

Comment: @JasonBourne In the `CAShapeLayer` example, you'd just change the `strokeColor` for each layer. In the subclassed `UIView` example, would not build a single path, but rather set `strokeColor`, `stroke` the first path, and go to the next one. It sort of depends upon what dictates the change of colors. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I kinda when a different direction. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903572/uibezierpath-multiple-line-colors @Rob

Comment: @JasonBourne My point is unchanged. You `setStroke` to set the color, you `stroke` to draw in that color. And repeat.

Answer (score 2):

UIBezierPath is building a path from your instructions. Imagine a pen. When you say, "moveToPoint:" it moves the pen to that point. When you say "lineToPoint:" it puts the pen down and moves it from the current location to the new point. And so on.

To get the effect you desire, you will need to create a new path whenever the touches move, drawing a line from the original point to the current touch position.

Comment: So on touchesEnded, I should set myPath to nil?

Comment: Why is this so complicated?

Comment: @Cirex18 On touchesBegan, save the point. On touchesMoved, create a path and draw it. On touchesEnded, save the final path.

Comment: @benzado that just gives me a fractal pattern(Multplie lines from the point of origin)

Comment: @Rob, i am trying to not use CAShapeLayer.

Comment: @benzado ok so I added myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init]; to the Touches moved. And that gives the desired effect. But it erases upon creating a new line.

Comment: @Cirex18 If you want to keep the old lines, too, you have to save them and redraw them every time. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14203167/1271826).