# Using Quartz for small graphic project

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm developing a iOS project that involves drawing small graphics (lines and paths) on the screen.

I initially chose to use Quartz instead of OpenGL, because I need to display some basic shapes and I need to update them every 5 seconds, so I thought Quartz was better and easier.

I found out that I can't simply draw in a view, but I have to subclass a UIView and draw in the drawRect method.

In my project, the user should be able to pinch and zoom on graphics, so I planned to add a pinchgesture to the view, but I am doubtful about how to redraw everything after the pinch. Do I have to erase everything and re-add the subviews so the drawRect will trigger or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: not a possible answer but check this http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-a-fun-iphone-app-called-bearded-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Quartz, you technically don't *have* to subclass the view and replace the `drawRect`, but it probably is best practice. When you want to redraw your window, just call `[self setNeedsDisplay];` (if calling from the subclassed view, or `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` if doing it from the view controller). This will result in calling your `drawRect` method for you and it takes care of everything for you.

See the [`setNeedsDisplay`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) documentation for more information.

Comment: so You mean that for example I change my drawing variables to new values and then trigger setNeedsDisplay, right?

Comment: @GavynSykes - Yep. See the second code example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14203167/1271826 for an example of combining a gesture and a `setNeedsDisplay`. Note, this is doing something slightly different than you are (this is animating the drawing of a line from the start of a gesture to the end of a gesture), but it illustrates (a) the integration of gestures and Quartz; (b) right time to call `setNeedsDisplay` in `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`; and (c) shows you the difference between doing it in your view controller or using a subclassed `UIView`.