# UIBezierPath Multiple Line Colors

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, uibezierpath

My attempt to draw UIBezierPath lines with different colors is failing me. All the lines change to the currently selected color. All my path and information are all stored in an NSMutableArray called pathInfo. In path info I drop in array that contains the Path, Color, Width, and Type of line. This works fine except all the lines turn to whatever color the user has selected. I would appreciate any help greatly!

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *drawPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    drawPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    drawPath.miterLimit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [pathInfo count]; i++){
        NSArray *row = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[pathInfo objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"Path: %@",[row objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"Color: %@",[row objectAtIndex:1]);
        NSLog(@"Width: %@",[row objectAtIndex:2]);
        NSLog(@"Type: %@",[row objectAtIndex:3]);

        //width
        drawPath.lineWidth = [[row objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];

        //color
        [[row objectAtIndex:1] setStroke];

        //path
        [drawPath appendPath:[row objectAtIndex:0]];

    }

   UIBezierPath *path = [self pathForCurrentLine];
    if (path)
     [drawPath appendPath:path];

   [drawPath stroke];
}

- (UIBezierPath*)pathForCurrentLine {
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(startPoint, CGPointZero) && CGPointEqualToPoint(endPoint, CGPointZero)){
        return nil;
    }

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:startPoint];
    [path addLineToPoint:endPoint];

    return path;

}
```

Comment: Please pass me your complete code for this if possible. Actually I am also facing same problem. But I am using touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnd method. I am not able to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stroke/fill colors only affect the `-stroke` command. They don't affect the `-appendPath:` command. Paths don't contain per-segment color information.

If you need a multi-colored line you're going to need to stroke each color separately.

Comment: And how do I do that @Kevin-Ballard

Comment: @JasonBourne: Instead of appending all your paths into one master path, just stroke each path in turn.

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing? Each one gets drawn in the for statement @kevin-ballard

Comment: @JasonBourne: No they don't. Each one gets appended to your `drawPath` path, and then at the end you stroke the `drawPath`.

Comment: So should I move the drawPath color,line,width etc.. to the pathForCurrentLine method? @Kevin-Ballard

Comment: @JasonBourne: I have no idea what's in your `-pathForCurrentLine` method, but certainly inside the for loop, instead of saying `[drawPath appendPath:[row objectAtIndex:0]]` you should just say `[[row objectAtIndex:0] stroke]`.

Comment: The pathForCurrentLine is in the bottom portion of the code @kevin-ballard

Comment: @Kevin-Ballad Thanks! you just prevented me from going bald!

Comment: Oh so it is. I just had to scroll. In any case, you should just be able to stroke that path directly in your `-drawRect:`, after setting whatever stroke color you want.

Answer (score 3):

Set your stroke color (and what have you), then `stroke`, and then move to the next path:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [pathInfo count]; i++){
        NSArray *row = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[pathInfo objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSLog(@"Path: %@",[row objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"Color: %@",[row objectAtIndex:1]);
        NSLog(@"Width: %@",[row objectAtIndex:2]);
        NSLog(@"Type: %@",[row objectAtIndex:3]);

        UIBezierPath *path = [row objectAtIndex:0];

        path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
        path.miterLimit = 0;

        //width
        path.lineWidth = [[row objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];

        //color
        [[row objectAtIndex:1] setStroke];

        //path
        [path stroke];
    }

    UIBezierPath *path = [self pathForCurrentLine];
    if (path)
    {
        // set the width, color, etc, too, if you want
        [path stroke];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow your answer is also valid! I appreciate your help too Rob! This method does seem to work better.