# How to create two strokes of different color using one UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw  lines on a `UIView` with finger and it worked fine with one color. If I try to change the color and draw again, the previous `UIBezierPath` color is also changed to new color. So, I am unable to draw a different color line keeping the previous color line on the `UIView`

I set all the properties(path,linecolor) as nonatomic and strong in my `UIView`

For reference:

my first draw:[image]

my second draw:[image]

my third draw: [image]

After I choose the color, I change the stroke color of my UIView in color picker delegate method:

```
#pragma mark - FCColorPickerViewControllerDelegate Methods

-(void)colorPickerViewController:(FCColorPickerViewController *)colorPicker didSelectColor:(UIColor *)color {

      self.drawView.lineColor = color; //this works fine 

 //    self.drawView.path=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];  tried this to create new bezier path with new color, but this erases the olde bezier path and return new
//    [self.drawView.lineColor setStroke];     tried this
//    [self.drawView.lineColor setFill];  tried this

      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //dismiss the color picker
}
```

Here are my view methods for drawing:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder 
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:self.lineWidth];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame 
{
    [self.lineColor setStroke];

    [path stroke];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
        [path moveToPoint:p];
    });

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
       CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
       [path addLineToPoint:p];
       [self setNeedsDisplay];
   });
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

I tried [this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903572/uibezierpath-multiple-line-colors) adding the old bezier paths to the array and redraw them, but it didnt work , this time I cant make another bezier path with new color.:

```
       - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame // (5)
{
    //load the path from array
    for (int i = 0; i < [pathArray count]; i++){


        NSLog(@"Path: %@",[pathArray objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"Color: %@",[pathArray objectAtIndex:1]);

        UIBezierPath *oldpath = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];

         //color
        [[pathArray objectAtIndex:1] setStroke];

        //path
        [oldpath stroke];
    }

    UIBezierPath *newPath = [self pathForCurrentLine];
    if (newPath)
    {
        // set the width, color, etc, too, if you want
         [lineColor setStroke];
        [newPath stroke];
    }

}

   - (UIBezierPath*)pathForCurrentLine {
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(startPoint, CGPointZero) && CGPointEqualToPoint(endPoint, CGPointZero)){
        return nil;
    }

    UIBezierPath *newpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [newpath moveToPoint:startPoint];
    [newpath addLineToPoint:endPoint];

    return newpath;

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
        [path moveToPoint:p];
        startPoint=p;
    });

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
       CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
       [path addLineToPoint:p]; // (4)
       endPoint=p;

       [self setNeedsDisplay];
   });
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    [pathArray addObject:path];
    [pathArray addObject:lineColor];

}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: You should make a fresh  bezier path every time the user lifts his finger, or everytime the color is changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually can't stroke different parts of the same path in different colors.

You can think of the drawing context as a state machine.  Each time you issue a draw command (such as calling `stroke` on a `UIBezierPath`) it will check the current stroke/fill color and use that to perform the draw.  To create multiple strokes in different colors you would need to have multiple paths to stroke, and set the stroke color in between each invocation of `stroke`.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame {
    UIBezierPath* pathOne = // create path one
    UIBezierPath* pathTwo = // create path two
    UIBezierPath* pathThree = // create path three

    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [pathOne stroke];

    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
    [pathTwo stroke];

    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    [pathThree stroke];
}
```

Comment: if i create a new bezier path, what will happen to my old one? I declared the bezierpath as a property. Do I need to set that property to new path? Please give an example

Comment: Overtime `drawRect:` is invoked you must redraw everything that needs to be on screen.  If you need to keep your old paths, you will have to keep an array of paths that all get drawn each time `drawRect:` is invoked.

Comment: Also, you need to implement `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`, even if it just does the same thing as `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.  It's important to implement all four of the `UIResponder` touch handling methods if you implement any of them so superviews don't get partial touch method invocations.