# How to draw a single UIBezierPath with multiple colors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibezierpath

I have a draw board  project that needs to draw a `UIBezierPath` with **multiple** color.
  I use method `addLineToPoint()` to append my path and

```
resultColor.set() 

path.stroke()
```

to draw the path every time after `addLineToPoint` is called.All I want is each segment of the path have different color depend on the back ground color.I have already had the result color (different point has its color), but when I use the methods above when I drawing, the color of the whole path is changing to the latest point's result color , but I want is a path like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lM3d.jpg)
(assuming that it is a single UIBezierPath)

How can I deal with the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903572/uibezierpath-multiple-line-colors

Comment: Thanks but what I want to know is how to draw a single UIBezierPath with different color.